# Поиск компьютера в сети

Tags: сеть, .net, клиент-сервер, c#

Здравствуйте!) Имеется программа по типу клиент-сервер, но она может выступать как клиент и как сервер) Т.е. имеется группа компьютеров соединенных в сеть по Wifi, на каждом стоит эта программа. На одном из компьютере в программе ставиться галочка, что я сервер, значит все остальные должны осуществить его поиск и присоединиться к нему - клиенты. Далее через определенное время сервер начинает рассылать сообщения по своему требованию, а также по требованию клиентов. Как найти сервер?

Иначе же зная заранее имя компьютера-сервера можно подключиться к нему, но как узнать его IP в сети автоматически?

Да, можно конечно же через ipconfig узнать ip, указать его в клиенте и подключится) Но как это сделать автоматически?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

В локальном сегменте Ethernet сети это делается посылкой bradcast udp пакета (всем на заданный порт) на который сервер отвечает конкретно отправителю (получив этот пакет из него узнаем IP сервера).

Для нелокальной подсети этот метод работает только если на роутерах разрешен "внешний" broadcast (обычно админы закрывают его).

Будет ли bradcast udp работать в WiFi не знаю (но попробуйте искать в этом направлении).